# Django i want to query only is_delete False ,how can i restricted it

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

so i have model in that have one field  is_delete  false defaults ,if it become true then, while  queried like Model.obects.all(), is_delete  True,  queryset should  not came .queryset have query of only is_delete False

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter method :
e.g. Model.objects.filter(is_delete=False)

Comment: every time i have to use the filter method, so i want to avoid that method . it means  that  i want auto excluded data with is_delete = True

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `.objects` manager with:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            is_delete=False
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    is_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem